Interpret chrome lighthouse score
I've be running Chrome lighthouse on a website and the results it gives out is not what the chrome documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/performance-scoring.
The score comes out of 22 which is strange as seen below.

Does that mean if we took a percentage its 50%? or is there a different way to interpret this output?
Thanks alot
